# deSolve ODE in R - changing variable with time

Tags: r, parameters, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to get an ODE system where a variable (FA2) is changing with **every** time step to work. I have the following code.

Note: FA2 is defined as FA2=b+a*i and cannot get larger than 90

The model function:

```
model <- function(times, y, pars) {
  with(as.list(c(pars, y)), {
    # set up vector of FA2 values   
    FA2_1=c()
    for (i in 1:90){
      FA2_1[i]=b+i*a
    }
    FA2_1=c(b,FA2_1)
 # make ifelse statement   
    FA=ifelse(FA2_1>=90,90,FA2_1)
    FA2=c()
     for (i in 1:length(times)){
      FA2[i]=ifelse(times[i]>TR,FA[i],FA[1])
    }

# the ode system
dS <- -k1*S-(1/T1s)*S-S*(1-cos(FA1*pi/180))/TR 
dP <-  k1*S-(1/T1p)*P-P*(1-cos(FA2*pi/180))/TR 

list(c(dS,dP))
  })
}

y = c(S = 1 ,P=0) # initial values

parms=c(k1=0.016,T1p=57,T1s=36) # pars

times=c(0,2,4,6,8,10) # time vector

a=1 # can be any positive value this is just an example
b=12 # can be any positive value this is just an example
TR=2 # can be any positive value
FA1=1 # cen be any positive value
```

**Output**:

```
  out1=ode(y, times, model,parms)
    out1=data.frame(out1)
```

The problem right now seems to be that the solver ignores the different values of the FA2 from the `ifelse` statement and just picks the first element of `FA2[1]=12` from the FA2 vector.

I have tried just to give the function the statement of

```
FA2=ifelse(times>=2,FA[2],FA[1])
```

instead of the statement posted in the function as:

```
FA2=c()
   for (i in 1:length(times)){
          FA2[i]=ifelse(times[i]>TR,FA[i],FA[1])
        }
```

and the small `ifelse` statement without a loop seems to make the solver react to changing values of a. however, I need more than just the first value of the FA vector when time steps are changing. does anyone have any idea of how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you give us an idea how `pars`, `y`, and `times` look like? Is `length(times) == length(FA)` always `TRUE`?

Comment: yes 'length(times) == length(FA)' is always 'TRUE'. times in this case is the vector of  c(0,2,4,6,8,10) and at every time step the FA2 is suppose to go up with the value of 1. pars are in this case forgotten (sorry) here they are 'parms=c(k1=0.016,T1p=57,T1s=36)' also the TR=2 in this case and FA1=1

Comment: also the y is the initial conditions of the system

Comment: @shesia In your function `model`, `times` is always length one because it is **not** the length of the vector `times` defined *outside* the function, but instead it is the length of the parameter `times` which is passed to `model`. That parameter is the current time of the simulation and is therefore a single number. To avoid confusion, why not call the times that you want model output as `times` and the current time of the model (i.e., the first parameter of the `model` function) as `t`?